# Is Python bz2file slower than bz2?

Tags: python, performance, bzip2

I have a Python script that parses BZ2 compressed logfiles using regex.

We were getting pretty poor performance, which I initially thought was my regex - however, when I looked further, it seems bz2file was performing poorly.

We are using Python 2.6, and bz2file 0.9.

I've noticed that sequentially reading the file using Bz2file (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bz2file) appears substantially slower than that using the in-built bz2 implementation.

I wrote two test scripts - one using bz2:

```
import bz2
filename = 'some_bz2file.bz2'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = bz2.BZ2File(filename, 'rb')
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

and another using bz2file:

```
import bz2file
filename = 'some_bz2file.bz2'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = bz2file.BZ2File(filename, 'rb')
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

I time them both:

```
$ time python26 testbz.py  > /dev/null

real    0m0.608s
user    0m0.596s
sys     0m0.011s

$ time python26 testbz2file.py > /dev/null

real    0m12.035s
user    0m11.952s
sys     0m0.075s
```

For comparison, bzcat on the same file:

```
$ time bzcat some_bz2file.bz2 > /dev/null

real    0m0.503s
user    0m0.499s
sys     0m0.004s
```

My understanding was that bz2file was just a wrapper about bz2, but adding handling for multiple-stream BZ2 files (which we do use).

Is there any other reason why bz2file might be so much slower than bz2? (Or is my analysis above flawed?) And if so, is there any way to speed up bz2file?

Cheers,
Victor

Edit - I did some more testing, including on Python 3.3 - apparently bz2file is a backport of Python 3.3's bz2 module - and also flushing caches as jordanm suggests (I did this in a separate terminal between each run, as root):

```
[vichoo@dev_desktop_vm Desktop]$ time /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 testbz2.py > /dev/null

real    0m5.170s
user    0m5.009s
sys     0m0.030s
[vichoo@dev_desktop_vm Desktop]$ time /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 testbz2file.py > /dev/null

real    0m5.245s
user    0m4.979s
sys     0m0.060s
[vichoo@dev_desktop_vm Desktop]$ time /opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7 testbz2.py > /dev/null

real    0m0.500s
user    0m0.410s
sys     0m0.030s
[vichoo@dev_desktop_vm Desktop]$ time /opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7 testbz2file.py > /dev/null

real    0m5.801s
user    0m5.529s
sys     0m0.050s
```

There does seem to be something funny here, not sure if it's my methodology, or if there is an actual performance regression between Python 2.x's bz2 and Python 3.x's bz2.

Comment: Anytime you do performance comparison on something that involves I/O, you should flush the kernel's disk cache. In Linux, you can use `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I've added that in, and run the tests, and also added in Python 3.x.

Comment: For any who find this via google: The OP has reported it and a fix has been issued. http://bugs.python.org/issue16034